# PHP date function displaying wrong day

Tags: php, date

I am trying to get todays day using PHP date function but it is coming back with 31/03/2013 which is tomorrow. I have tried changing the default timezone but it still returns the same.

```
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Dublin');
    echo date("d/m/Y");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the server-time is correct?
Also today may be a bad day to test dates since many countries switch DST

Comment: It's on my windows PC running WAMP. The date on the systray clock is correct unless there is somewhere else I should be checking?

Comment: Can you do `echo time()` both before and after `date_default_timezone_set`?

Comment: Yep. The timezone seems to be correct as the time stamp doesn't change when I add/remove the date_default_timezone_set()

Answer (score -2):

Looks to like bug in php 5.3.2-1. Try to run the php script in the bug report and post your results.

Comment: -1 vote for : look at here http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php , at the end of the example 4 , there is a statement , `To format dates in other languages, you should use the setlocale() and strftime() functions instead of date(). `

Comment: @CooPer that link to the fix is dead

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php